# Problem to correctly obtain more solds and visited items in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting the total of **most sold** and total **most viewed** products correctly.

Case best sellers:

```
   SELECT p.product_id, p.title, p.description, p.specifications, p.price, p.discount, p.discount_type, p.color, p.hours, p.product_type, p.gender, p.img, p.vdo_intro, p.status, p.url, p.date_start, p.date_end, p.ip, p.product_page, p.product_code, p.brand,   p.color_url,                          
          c.category_id, c.category_url as urlcategory, c.parent,
          SUM(o.order_quantity) as solds
     FROM order_detail o
     JOIN product p ON o.product_id = p.product_id                      
     JOIN category_relations rcat ON rcat.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN `category` c on rcat.category_id = c.category_id  
  WHERE p.gender = ? AND p.status=1 AND p.date_end IS NULL 
 GROUP BY p.product_id
 ORDER BY SUM(o.order_quantity)
     DESC LIMIT 12;
```

In Data Base i have:

```
id_order    order_quantity  order_price order_discount  order_discount_type product_id  order_date
    1           2               59.00        0               %                 1        2022-01-31 22:49:24
    2           5               59.00        0               %                20        2022-01-31 22:49:24
    3          12               59.00        0               %                 8        2022-01-31 22:49:24
    4           5               59.00        0               %                19        2022-01-31 22:49:24
    5          25               59.00        0               %                17        2022-01-31 22:49:24
    6           3               59.00        0               %                 1        2022-01-31 22:49:24
```

*Result i get :*

```
id:1    2 + 3 = 5 solds    i get = 20 solds (wrong). 
id:20   5 solds            i get = 15 solds (wrong).
id:8   12 solds            i get = 36 solds (wrong).
id:19   5 solds            i get = 5 solds (ok).
id:17  25 solds            i get = 50 solds (wrong).
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
It look like that it is multiplying the results by records.

Case most visits:

```
    SELECT p.product_id, p.title, p.description, p.specifications, p.price, p.discount, p.discount_type, p.color, p.hours, p.product_type, p.gender, p.img, p.vdo_intro, p.status, p.url, p.date_start, p.date_end, p.ip, p.product_page, p.product_code, p.brand, p.color_url,                       
           c.category_id, c.category_url as urlcategory, c.parent,
           SUM(v.total) as visits
      FROM `visits` v
      JOIN `product` p ON v.product_id = p.product_id
      JOIN category_relations rcat ON rcat.product_id = p.product_id 
 LEFT JOIN `category` c on rcat.category_id = c.category_id                                     
     WHERE p.gender = ? AND p.status=1 AND p.date_end IS NULL  
  GROUP BY p.product_id
  ORDER BY SUM(v.total)
      DESC LIMIT 12
```

My database:

```
id_visits   total      ip              today        product_id
23           5     xxxxxxxxxxxxx1   2022-02-09        1
36           1     xxxxxxxxxxxxx4   2022-02-06       13
40           1     xxxxxxxxxxxxx3   2022-02-06       13
41           1     xxxxxxxxxxxxx1   2022-02-06       21
48           1     xxxxxxxxxxxxx2   2022-02-07       13
50           1     xxxxxxxxxxxxx2   2022-02-07        1
62           1     xxxxxxxxxxxxx8   2022-02-08        1
```

*Result i get:*

```
id1 :   5 + 1 + 1 = 7 visits      i get 28 visits (wrong)
id13:   1 + 1 + 1 = 3 visits      i get 9 visits (wrong)
id21:   1         = 1 visits      i get 3 visits (wrong)
```

Does anyone know the error, because it does not add up correctly?

> note: I can add the tables if needed

**Edit:**

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8woBZmnMUpcoauemM1o5nq/1)

If i do:

`GROUP BY rcat.cat_relation_id`

I get the calculation right, but it repeats the same products

Comment: I think you should put the tables in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It will be easy to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Ruleboy21 I have updated my question, I have added a fiddle with the DB.

Comment: Add the desired result format, otherwise everybody is just guessing about what query to write.  The fiddle is very helpful, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that category_relations is a many to many table.  So when you join it you get additional results for each category that a product is in.  So product id1 is in 4 categories so you get a sum of 28 instead of 7.

Your query is producing a row for each order for each category that the product ordered is in and then grouping all rows with the same product_id together.  SUM will add all the values from all the rows grouped together.

If you want one line per product you need to group by product_id.  You could remove the category data (3 items in SELECT and 2 JOINS), but if you need that category data in that one line per product you need to aggregate the category data with an aggregate function such as GROUP_CONCAT(). Then you can fix the sum by dividing by the number of categories. You can get the number of categories with COUNT(DISTINCT category_id).

Your queries would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    p.title, 
    p.description, 
    p.specifications, 
    p.price, 
    p.discount, 
    p.discount_type, 
    p.color, 
    p.hours, 
    p.product_type, 
    p.gender, 
    p.img, 
    p.vdo_intro, 
    p.status, 
    p.url, 
    p.date_start, 
    p.date_end, 
    p.ip, 
    p.product_page, 
    p.product_code, 
    p.brand,
    p.color_url,                          
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_id) AS category_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_url) AS urlcategory, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.parent) AS parent,
    ROUND(SUM(o.order_quantity) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id)) AS solds
FROM        order_detail o
JOIN        product AS p ON o.product_id = p.product_id                      
JOIN        category_relations rcat ON rcat.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN   category AS c ON rcat.category_id = c.category_id  
WHERE
    p.gender = ? AND 
    p.status=1 AND 
    p.date_end IS NULL 
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(o.order_quantity) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id)) DESC 
LIMIT 12;


SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    p.title, 
    p.description, 
    p.specifications, 
    p.price, 
    p.discount, 
    p.discount_type, 
    p.color, 
    p.hours, 
    p.product_type, 
    p.gender, 
    p.img, 
    p.vdo_intro, 
    p.status, 
    p.url, 
    p.date_start, 
    p.date_end, 
    p.ip, 
    p.product_page, 
    p.product_code, 
    p.brand, 
    p.color_url, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_id) AS category_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_url) AS urlcategory, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.parent) AS parent,
    ROUND(SUM(v.total) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id)) AS solds
FROM 
            visits AS v
JOIN        product AS p ON v.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN        category_relations AS rcat ON rcat.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN   category AS c ON rcat.category_id = c.category_id                                     
WHERE
    p.gender = ? AND 
    p.status=1 AND 
    p.date_end IS NULL  
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(v.total) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id))
DESC LIMIT 12;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8woBZmnMUpcoauemM1o5nq/4)
(I commented some stuff in the fiddle to make it easier to see the results)

To have a consistent order for the category fields that were concatenated you can use an ORER BY clause in the GROUP CONCAT function:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_id ORDER BY c.category_id) AS category_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_url ORDER BY c.category_id) AS urlcategory, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.parent ORDER BY c.category_id) AS parent,
```

[MySQL doc for GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

If you only need one result from categories, let's say the category with the lowest id, you can use this trick:  You left join your category_relations again with a condition that category_id is lower than the first one and then in your WHERE clause only select the rows where that IS NULL - no lower category_id was found.

```
...
    c.category_id,
    c.category_url, 
    c.parent,
    ROUND(SUM(o.order_quantity) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id)) AS solds
FROM        order_detail o
JOIN        product AS p ON o.product_id = p.product_id                      
JOIN        category_relations rcat ON rcat.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN   category AS c ON rcat.category_id = c.category_id  
LEFT JOIN   category_relations AS rcat2 ON rcat.product_id = p.product_id AND rcat2.category_id < rcat.category_id
WHERE
    p.gender = ? AND 
    p.status=1 AND 
    p.date_end IS NULL AND
    rcat2.category_id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.product_id, c.category_id
ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(o.order_quantity) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id)) DESC 
...
```

Comment: I have change ```GROUP BY p.product_id``` for ```GROUP BY rcat.cat_relation_id```, now i get the calculation right, but it repeats the same products many times. Do you know what I need to add, so that it does not repeat itself?

Comment: If you want one row per product then you have to group by product. If you need to include the data from the category table then you will have to an aggregate function.  You can get the correct number of sales by dividing by categories.  I'll update my answer and use the DB Fiddle you provided.

Comment: Thanks, it works +1, now they don't repeat themselves, the only problem I have, is that now I don't believe the url correctly, when I get something like ```/sports,clothes,t-shirt,t-shirt-basic/```, and I really only need *clothes* or *sports* can work (this is on level 2), I could use ```explode()```, but they are not always in the same position, did you know how to solve this?

Comment: I could fix it by simply removing ```GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT``` on these lines and leave it like that: ```c.category_id AS category_id, c.category_url AS urlcategory, c.parent AS parent```, do you see it well, or is there a better way to get the level 2 category? in this case, i just have to be careful that the level 2 category is always registered first in table: *category_relations*

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'level 2' or how the urls in your application work, but you can add an ORDER BY clause to the GROUP_CONCAT function to have a consistent order when you use explode().

Comment: I only have one category table , example url i need: (**domain.com/moda-hombre/ropa/item**) now moda-hombre (mens fashion) is *level 1*, i add it manual by prefix, but i need *level 2* ropa (clothes), if parent is null it is level 1, if parent have an id it is a level 2, or 3, or 4, etc. On some occasions I do not get the URL correctly, because it does not order it, instead the category_id does come in order, I leave you an example fiddle, for example id 2 = clothes (ropa), or id 3 = shoes (zapatos) i need this in order like de category_id https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8woBZmnMUpcoauemM1o5nq/5

Comment: I don't know if you understand me with this example result from fiddle:  ```CFPREPSTERS - Shorts  id: 2,46,47  url: pantalones-cortos,pantalones-cortos-causal,ropa ```  ok, I tell you, id: 2 = ropa, and pantalones-cortos = id: 46, so the url i get is domain.com/moda-hombre/pantalones-cortos/item **wrong**, in this case i need domain.com/moda-hombre/ropa/item, that is on level 2

Comment: Ok, so I added the ORDER_BY clause to the GROUP_CONCAT functions as I suggested:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8woBZmnMUpcoauemM1o5nq/6

Comment: Thanks a lots, i have a little trouble understanding when they are complex, do like hobby. I've been trying to fix it all day XD. Will test it later :)

Comment: Thanks friend, it worked. I will analyze well the example and the manual that you have left me, I did not know that distinct and order by could be used in those parts. I will also try to obtain all the levels as you have commented, which is also interesting

Comment: No problem.  Best of luck with your application and thanks for the accepted answer.